# How do you retrieve an array based on user input?

Tags: php

This is the data in the text file [contain the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBmE1.png)

I have already store the data in the array
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuz2Y.png)

```
<?php
    if (!(isset($_GET['job_title']) && empty($_GET['job_title']))) {
        $job_title = $_GET['job_title'];
        echo $job_title;
        $filename = __DIR__ . '/jobpost.txt';
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            $data= null;
            $allData = array();
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $onedata = fgets($handle);
                if ($onedata != "") {
                    $data = explode("\t", $onedata);
                    $allData[] = $data;
                }
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($allData);
            echo "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "file does not exist";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p class=\"bg_danger\"> must enter the job title </p>";
    }
?>
```

My question is when user enter an input "software engineering" and based on the input value, must retrieve the related the array.

Comment: Not the best code or way to do it but given what you have, `if($data[1] == $_GET['job_title']) { // do something }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't forget to filter/sanitize your user inputs.

Now Check while storing data into the array if you can create a array with keys as "software engineering"[image: Like this]

if that's not possible you can loop through array once & create array you need

```
$arrNewDataArray = [];
foreach( $dataArray as $arr ){
    $arrNewDataArray[$arr[1]] = $arr;
}
```

Then you will be able to check if user input value is present in the array & retrieve it like below.

```
$userinput = 'software engineering';
$arrayYouNeed = [];
if( isset( $arrNewDataArray[$userinput] ) ) { 
   $arrayYouNeed = $arrNewDataArray[$userinput];
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to strlower the array key and the user input.